# Getting original message from Camel route after splitting

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, message-queue, spring-camel

I have a camel route which reads in messages in batches from a queue, processes the message and proceeds to send them one by one to an api and awaits the api response.

I am having issue with retrieving the original message recieved at the start when a 500 response is thrown.

I thought that the splitter returns the original message?

Here is my route:

```
    from(gatewayRouteConfig.getInputQueueEndpoint())
            .process(process1)
            .process(process2)
            .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOnly)
            .choice()
            .when().jsonpath("Message", true)
            .setBody(MESSAGE_WRAPPER_EXTRACTOR)
            .end()
            .split().method(messageSplitter, "splitMessages")
            .log(INFO, "Received Message : ${body}")
            .process(process3)
            .process(validate)
            .process(identity)
            .process(requestProcessor) //where the exception is thrown and the original message that is used in the exception handler is picking up
            .process(someService::gatewayResponseTimeStop)
            .process(someService::endToEndResponseStop)
            .process(someService::markGatewayDeliveryAsSuccess)
            .log("Completed processing...");
```

and here is my exception handler in the same class:

```
    private void configureExceptionHandlers() {

        onException(ProviderException.class) //thrown when 500 error occurs
            .useOriginalMessage() //picks message in the form the process(requestProcessor) method recieves it instead of start of route
            .handled(true)
            .log(ERROR, LOGGER, EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_WITH_STACKTRACE)
            .to(DLQ);
```

Comment: You may need `shareUnitOfWork` in order to use `useOriginalMessage`. `.split().method(messageSplitter, "splitMessages").shareUnitOfWork()`

Comment: yes that it is exactly what I been thinking too due to the split method having new bodies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by adding shareUnitOfWork

```
.split().method(activityMessageSplitter, "splitActivityMessages").shareUnitOfWork()
```